# Prestashop 1.6 - Add Email Variable - product name

Tags: email, variables, prestashop-1.6

The default variable for emails is `{products}` and it shows 5 pieces of info about a product. I need to have a variable for just the `product name` - I've checked all around but didn't find a clear enough explanation on how to add this. Any ideas?

Comment: If you need the product name only then why don't you simply delete the redundant product info from the email template?

Comment: Because the email template uses the `{products}` variable. I don't know how to modify that or how to make use of only the product name. Any tips?

Comment: Which email template do you want to modify?

Comment: Of a custom module. not sure if this helps but I tried to extract relevant info - here it is: http://www.codeshare.io/0yzmu

Comment: Could you share the email template too?